# Can you nest tags in pug without using extends?

Tags: pug

I've read through the docs and I can't seem to find a way to nest tags as `block` only seems to be able to [`append`](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#block-append-prepend), [`prepend`](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html#block-append-prepend), or overwrite existing content in the block. Here's what I mean:

If I do this:

```
//- layout.pug
body
    block content
        main: container-fluid

//- random-page.pug
append content
    .row: .col
```

The generated HTML looks like this:

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid"></div>
  </main>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to get this result?

```
<body>
  <main>
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>
```

---

I know that [`extends`](https://pugjs.org/language/inheritance.html) allows you to nest tags, but it doesn't work for multi-tiered templating. Hopefully, that makes sense, but if it doesn't I can provide an example.

Comment: Make `block content` a child of `.container-fluid`

Comment: I think I know what you're asking, but could you provide a deeper example of what you want to do?

Comment: I'm essentially wanting to know if there is a way to insert content into a block rather than place content before/after the block. Does that help?